# TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an api that is populating data on a table, am trying to calculate the values of all the values in all the columns, the challenge am facing is that the columns contains both strings and numbers, am using a reducer to take a list of numbers and strings and reduce them down to a sum. I end up getting an  error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
> at AgedisplacementComponent.getSum

what I have done so far

```
export class AgeDisplacement {
  constructor(
    public num1 : string,
    public num2: number,
    public num3: number,
    public num4: number,
    public num5: number,
  ) {
  }
}
    export class AgedisplacementmenComponent implements OnInit {
      agemen: AgeDisplacement[];
      private api = ServiceConstants.apiUrl + '/api/v1/agedisplacement/goods';
    
      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
                  private modalService: ModalService,
                  private service: ReportService) {
      }

    getSum(index: number) : number{
    
        let sum = 0;
          for(let i = 0; i < this.agemen.length; i++) {
            sum = this.agemen[i][index].reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
              return accumulator + (!isNaN(Number(currentValue)) ? 0 : Number(currentValue));
            });
            console.log("data is " + sum);
          }
          return sum;
      }
```

sample data that `this.agemen` holds

```
{
        "id": 22,
        "teamNumber": "Group 1",
        "sex": 1,
        "age12": 0,
        "age13": 0,
        "age14": 0,
        "age15": 0,
        "age16": 0,
        "age17": 1,
        "age18": 0,
        "noofwomen": 1,
        "ageratio": " DEFAULT",
        "targetnotmet": " DEFAULT"
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "teamNumber": "Group 2",
        "sex": 1,
        "age12": 0,
        "age13": 0,
        "age14": 0,
        "age15": 1,
        "age16": 0,
        "age17": 0,
        "age18": 1,
        "noofwomen": 2,
        "ageratio": 34,
        "targetnotmet": 45
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "teamNumber": "Group 3",
        "sex": 1,
        "age12": 0,
        "age13": 0,
        "age14": 0,
        "age15": 0,
        "age16": 0,
        "age17": 0,
        "age18": 0,
        "noofwomen": 0,
        "ageratio": " DEFAULT",
        "targetnotmet": " DEFAULT",
    },
```

How I need to sum all that columns below like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
     <td>{{item.num1 }}</td>
     <td>{{item.num2}}</td>
     <td>{{item.num3}}</td>
     <td>{{item.num4}}</td>
     <td>{{item.num5}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>SUM1</td>
     <td>SUM2</td>
     <td>SUM3</td>
     <td>SUM4</td>
     <td>SUM5</td>
</tr>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample data that `this.agemenBaisv` holds?

Comment: Hi @Kiran shared

Comment: What do you need the sum of? I"m guessing that the data you provided is an Array of Objects. When you do `this.agemenBaisv[i]`, what you get is an Object which probably doesn't have the `"index"` property that you are passing to your `getSum` function.

Comment: Hi @Kiran I need the sum of all items in all columns. Yes the data is an Array of Objects. The index returns the columns, the i loops through the items within the columns

Comment: Is this what you want: `age12sum = this.agemen[0].age12 + this.agemen[1].age12 + ...`, `age13sum = this.agemen[0].age13 + this.agemen[1].age13 ...`

Comment: Hi @Kiran yes tats what  I want to achieve

Comment: @arriff where you set value of index? please update your question with complete required code then it will easy to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Hi @Wajid have updated

Comment: getSum(index: number) : number   from where this function is called ?? 
Form where you passed index?? actually issue with your index. you did not get index thats why its says undefine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is an array of object, looping over this, you'll get an Object, which won't have any `index` property that you are accessing via `this.agemen[i][index]`. `index` that you are passing to `getSum` won't really give you what you want. What you want is a `propertyName` which could be the property whose sum you want to get i.e the property that your column displays eg: `'age12'`, `'age13'` etc. Instead of passing a `propertyName`, you could also keep your own map of which column index holds which property. Eg:

```js
const columnNumberToPropertyMap = Object.freeze({
    0: 'id',
    1: 'age12', // assuming you display `age12` property's value on 2nd column
    2: 'age13',
    3: 'age14'
    // ... and so on.
});
```

So, depending on if you use a map or instead pass a `propertyName` to `getSum` you can change your function to something like this:

```js
getSum(columnNumber: number) : number {
    return this.agemen.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const property = columnNumberToPropertyMap[columnNumber]; // If you pass `property` directly to function, you don't need this lin
        const adder = isNaN(Number(curr[property])) ? 0 : Number(curr[property]); // you are doing just the opposite here

        return acc + adder;
    }, 0);
}

// Now wherever you want to get the sum of a column, for eg: 2nd column which holds the value of `age12` property, you can do:
getSum(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

getSum(index: number) : number from where this function is called ?? Form where you passed index?? actually issue with your index. you did not get index thats why its says undefine

You need to check index if it come correctly then it will work remember it must be within array length

```
  getSum(index: number) : number{
        
            let sum = 0;
              for(let i = 0; i < this.agemen.length; i++) {
                sum = this.agemen[i][index].reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
                  return accumulator + (!isNaN(Number(currentValue)) ? 0 : Number(currentValue));
                });
                console.log("data is " + sum);
              }
              return sum;
          }
```